# Why is my if statement not giving me the intended result?

Tags: if-statement, octave

Given a set of elements (expressed in a row vector `Vi`) I extracted the maximum values into another (row) vector (named 'ki') using `[ki] = find(Vi==max(max(Vi)))`. I say value**s** because a lot of numbers repeat. I have to choose randomly between all the repeated values and know the column of the chosen one. For that i made the following code.

```
ri=rand(1)

for j=1:length(ki)
  if    ((j-1)/length(ki)<ri<=j/length(ki))
    mi=ki(j)
  endif;
endfor  

if (ri==0)
  mi=ki(1)
endif
```

The problem is that it *always* gives me `mi=ki(last 'j' of the for cycle)` (which in this case is `mi=ki(length(ki))`). Why?

Comment: hey why so many votes down... :/

Comment: just pointing out the `find` function doesn't give you the maximum *values* but their *indices*. Should your `ki` be `ki = Vi(Vi == max(Vi(:)));` instead?

Comment: No. The values are not important for what i intend to build. when ready it could be interesting for people to view it, asi it is a basic mathematical model of social behaviour in butterflies. Is there a place here to just post codes and invite people to use it as they please?

Comment: StackOverflow is mostly a Q & A site, so it wouldn't really be relevant to this site. If this is university related, then I'd encourage you to start an academic blog and post this as one of your articles. Blogs are increasingly becoming a very useful tool for academics these days. Also, you could offer your project as an open-source project on github, etc.

Comment: as for values vs indices, fair enough, it *did* seem like you were after the indices rather than the values from the way you were iterating ... I was just commenting because you mentioned the word "values", just to make sure.

Comment: also, "the social behaviour of butterflies"? omg you ***have*** to put this cartoon in one of your presentations!!! http://realfunny.net/uploads/youve_changed._6436809655.jpg

Comment: Dont understand if you are joking. If not you can check more on that (google scholar) in the works about "virtual corridors" (Pe'er et al. 2005, Railsback-Grimm 2012)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou: Are you trying to get a master in the art of procrastination? I just ask because you answer every Octave related question in length :-)

Comment: @Andy hahah, let's just pretend I took Saturday "off" :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `((j-1)/length(ki)<ri<=j/length(ki))` doesn't do what you think it does. Matlab / Octave does not support "chaining" of operations. Your logical test should instead be:

```
((j-1)/length(ki)) < ri && ri <= (j/length(ki))
```

Instead what you're doing is calculating `((j-1)/length(ki)) < ri` first, which will give you either a `0` or a `1`, and you're then checking if that `0` or `1` is smaller or equal to `(j/length(ki))`

Comment: Thanks! You have and extra bracket. The correct code is ((j-1)/length(ki) < ri && (ri <= j/length(ki)))

Comment: I see you're a new user. Welcome to the community. If this answer solves your problem please mark it as accepted; also upvote all answers you feel are useful / interesting (including, the accepted one).
Also, I'm guessing the reason you had downvotes is because one of the main requests to users posting questions here is to provide minimal working examples (sometimes also known as [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) so that people can try them out on their machine. It's a lot harder to help when you can't run and debug things on the screen, so people treat these as bad questions.

Comment: Also, I suspect the title of your question is triggering knee-jerk reactions to people who hate "why isn't my code working" questions (as opposed to specific questions). I'll edit your title and make it a bit more palatable if you don't mind.